# Getting env variables to an NGNIX react kubernetes pod

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I have an ngnix kubernetes pod that I need to pass an `.env` file to but I can't get it to work.

Docker file for the pod:

```sh
FROM node:12-alpine as build-step

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I've tried with to pass the env with the configmap:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-front-app
data:
  ENV_TEST: "TEST"
```

And with passing the `env` in the `Deployment` but neither worked.

edit the deployment file:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-front-app
  name: test-front-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: test-front-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: test-front-app
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gcr-json-key
      containers:
      - name: front-test
        image: gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE:TAG
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
          - name: TEST_ONE
            value: "test-value-one/"
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: test-front-app
```

Comment: can you add `pod` manifest file ?

Comment: added the deployment file

Answer (score 2):

Your ConfigMap `test-front-app` key can be accessed as env like below.

```
    env:
    - name: TEST_ONE
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: test-front-app
          key: ENV_TEST
```

In this way `TEST_ONE` variable with value of `TEST` will be passed to deployment.

Comment: I've tried it like this, but its not working. I'm accessing the env like this: `process.env.TEST_ONE` but its not showing

Comment: Also I'm adding this env to the deploymrnt, should it be added to the pod kind in kubernetes?

Comment: Just to check config-map key is mapped as env var inside pod, exec to pod and check env vars.